# Why do modern OS need so much memory?

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system, legacy

I'm keeping an old university friends house. I found two of our old computers we used to hack on. They aren't even that old, like 2003 type. Single core, 256MB, 80GB hard drives. Or at least the stickers proudly proclaim.

So I go: Jackpot! I'm going to install Ubuntu and have some fun. But these machines have 256MB of ram. And with hardware use, it's more like less than 190 MB. And no modern linux/bsd distro seems to work on them. At least without MAJOR swap going on, like 30 minutes plus. For every operation.

Now, these machines used to run Windows xp without a hitch. Super fast.

Why have modern OS'es have such large memory requirements? I don't get it. Can someone tell me why they need so much memory? Just claiming sloppy programming or "modern" requirements isn't going to satisfy me.

Can someone give me an actual example of why a modern OS can't run on, say, 16MB of ram?

How can windows XP be so light, yet I can't seem to find linux distro that can run on such a system.

I'm pretty sure I used to program, surf the web, and even game on those old piece of junks. Now they can't even run anything beyond FreeDos?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; it is not about computer programming.

Comment: OSes are computer programs and the tendency to "bloat" is common to many other domains, so I think this is a relevant question about computer programming. Vote to stay open.

Comment: Windows XP was not a "light" OS. If you want a light OS, pick any  Linux or BSD distro contemporaneous with XP, such as Red Hat Linux 7 or FreeBSD 4. Or any such OS released in the next several years *following* 2001. Linux didn't start getting as tubby as XP until Ubuntu started to really catch on, starting with version 6.06 or so.

Comment: I should point out that there *are* still "light" versions of Linux, and most of the BSDs remain "light" OSes in their stock form. You have to add a lot of stuff to FreeBSD or Arch Linux to make them as fat as XP, for instance, and there are pared-down GUI Linuxes like [CrunchBang](http://crunchbang.org) that run well on really old hardware like that.

Comment: Yes. Update. I've been able to run both as headless, surprisingly responsible headless servers. As long as there is no graphics involved it seems that most of my problems go away. Another problem is pre-allocation, which pre-eats food without ever seeing it, which I find wasteful. I forget which, but I saw one service eat 128 MB of ram and need less than 2 MB of that space. I'm quite lucky, I have these "drones" to work with that are fast and agile, as long as I SSH into them.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that Operating Systems are written for the available hardware.

Those that are not (looking at you OS/2) lose market share and die.

The OS provides facilities that are achievable on the given target hardware, and, ignores features that would not be feasible on the target hardware.

So a modern OS expects at least a couple of GB and tunes the IO system to use large buffers, and caches lots of stuff an older OS would leave on disk. A modern OS expects a fast graphics processor and implements lots of silly eye-candy like transparent windows, 3d shading etc.

Dumb reviewers judge software packages on "feature count" so even open source developers feel obliged to match the feature list of commercial products -- most of which are never used.

As machines get more powerful developers feel their time is better spent improving reliability and adding functionality rather than space saveing and performance tweaks.

`<opiniated gripe`>As the state of the art in computer science evolves there is a tendancy to massivly overengineer producing complex solutions for simple problems`</opiniated gripe>`

Take a look here [one of these](http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/10-best-minimal-low-footprint-linux-distros/) should fit the bill.